# FlutterFire: No implementation found for method StorageReference#getDownloadUrl

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

When I try to get the download URL of a photo stored at Firebase Storage I get this error message in VS Code:

> Exception has occurred. MissingPluginException
>   (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method
>   StorageReference#getDownloadUrl on channel
>   plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage))

This is how I'm getting the download URL:

```
final String path = book['id'] + '/book-cover.jpg'; // this is just a mock for now
final StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(path);

ref.getDownloadURL()
  .then((value) => print('URL is:' + value));
```

I have the following imported in my dart file:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
```

And this is my pubspec:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  redux: ^3.0.0
  firebase_core: ^0.3.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.9.0
  firebase_storage: ^2.0.0
```

Comment: I feel like this is happening because you haven't uploaded anything to the reference.

Comment: I have uploaded the file manually using Firebase console.

Even if I hardcode the path I get the same error.

Storage rules are set to public btw.

Comment: @Rafff how did you fixed? I have the same problem now.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to update your GoogleServices files.